# Appropriate Transformation for 3D-looking 2D drawing (Java)

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, 2d

I'm looking for the appropriate transformation to make a 2D image look like a 3D drawing. If I draw a "road" with parallel lines on a sheet of paper, and then tilt the top of the page away from you, so that the road appears to be disappearing into the distance is what I am looking for.

I'm using Java and would like an appropriate API/library. I don't believe "AffineTransformation" accomplishes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want an AffineTransformation, as that will always preserve parallel lines, which isn't what you want here.

Luckily the Java Advanced Imaging API (`javax.media.jai`) has exactly what you want, in the shape of the `PerspectiveTransform` class (click that link for docs).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a simple answer, but I can tell you that what you're looking to draw is called two-point perspective. With this information, maybe you will be able to find a library that takes a 3D object and produces a perspective view.

Here's a simple Java applet that I've seen previously that demonstrates 2-point perspective:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170929161127/http://mathforum.org/workshops/sum98/participants/sanders/TryPersp.gsp.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not trivial, but certainly solvable. You can take any four-sided image and apply a 3D perspective transformation. Just don't expect it to be a one-liner.

I'm at home now (checking SO before going to sleep, of course :D), but I'm almost 100% certain this is the site I used to find the appropriate code in C#:

http://ryoushin.com/cmerighi/en-us/61,2007-10-29/Image_Distortion_Enhancements.aspx

Porting it to java should be fairly straightforward. Let me know if the link doesn't solve your answer and I'll edit my answer tomorrow with more info.